# Jackson : deserializing a map

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson to deserialize a json file from a HTTP Response:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    InputStream responseBody = response.getBody().in();
    RawDataBody rawdataBody = mapper.readValue(responseBody, RawDataBody.class);
```

I also tries this but it doesn't work :

```
RawDataBody rawdataBody = mapper.readValue(responseBody.toString(), RawDataBody.class);
```

This is the error that I'm getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.ubiant.hemis.accounts.TineaSeas.Model.RawDataBody out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@19da0cd; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:569)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1120)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:148)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:123)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2080)
at com.ubiant.hemis.accounts.TineaSeas.Test.main(Test.java:46)
```

The JSON File :`

```
[
   {  
  "tag":"Volume_D1_10m",
  "value":0.0,
  "quality":1,
  "site":1,
  "supplier":2,
  "zone":0,
  "timestamp":1470297561000
 },
   {  
  "tag":"Tmoy_T4_10m",
  "value":19.2,
  "quality":1,
  "site":1,
  "supplier":2,
  "zone":0,
  "timestamp":1470297561000
 }
]
```

This is my model :`

```
public class RawDataBody implements Serializable  {

@JsonProperty("rawDatas")
@JsonDeserialize
private ArrayList<RawData> rawDatas = new ArrayList<RawData>();

public RawDataBody(){     
}

public RawDataBody rawDatas(ArrayList<RawData> rawDatas) {
    this.rawDatas = rawDatas;
    return this;
}

@JsonProperty("rawDatas")
public ArrayList<RawData> getRawDatas() {
    return rawDatas;
}

@JsonProperty("rawDatas")
public void setRawDatas(ArrayList<RawData> rawDatas) {
    this.rawDatas = rawDatas;
}


public class RawData implements Serializable  {

private String tag = null;  
private Double value = null;
private Integer quality = null;
private Integer site = null;
private Integer supplier = null;
private Integer zone = null;
private BigDecimal timestamp = null;


@JsonProperty("tag")
public String getTag() {
  return tag;
}

@JsonProperty("tag")
public void setTag(String tag) {
  this.tag = tag;
}

@JsonProperty("value")
public Double getValue() {
  return value;
}

@JsonProperty("value")
public void setValue(Double value) {
  this.value = value;
}


@JsonProperty("quality")
public Integer getQuality() {
  return quality;
}

@JsonProperty("quality")
public void setQuality(Integer quality) {
  this.quality = quality;
}


@JsonProperty("site")
public Integer getSite() {
  return site;
}
@JsonProperty("site")
public void setSite(Integer site) {
  this.site = site;
}


@JsonProperty("supplier")
public Integer getSupplier() {
  return supplier;
}

@JsonProperty("supplier")
public void setSupplier(Integer supplier) {
  this.supplier = supplier;
}



@JsonProperty("zone")
public Integer getZone() {
  return zone;
}
@JsonProperty("zone")
public void setZone(Integer zone) {
  this.zone = zone;
}
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
public BigDecimal getTimestamp() {
  return timestamp;
}

@JsonProperty("timestamp")
public void setTimestamp(BigDecimal timestamp) {
  this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

}

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: The message is accurate - you cannot deserialize a list to a class.  Do you want to produce a list of `RawDataBody` instances?

Comment: I want to produce a list of RawData which is the field of the class RawDataBody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approaches:

### Approach 1

Considering the existing JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "tag": "Volume_D1_10m",
    "value": 0,
    "quality": 1,
    "site": 1,
    "supplier": 2,
    "zone": 0,
    "timestamp": 1470297561000
  },
  {
    "tag": "Tmoy_T4_10m",
    "value": 19.2,
    "quality": 1,
    "site": 1,
    "supplier": 2,
    "zone": 0,
    "timestamp": 1470297561000
  }
]
```

It can be serialized into a `RawData` array, as following:

```java
String json = "[{\"tag\":\"Volume_D1_10m\",\"value\":0.0,\"quality\":1,\"site\":1,\"supplier\":2,\"zone\":0,\"timestamp\":1470297561000},{\"tag\":\"Tmoy_T4_10m\",\"value\":19.2,\"quality\":1,\"site\":1,\"supplier\":2,\"zone\":0,\"timestamp\":1470297561000}]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
RawData[] rawDataArray = mapper.readValue(json, RawData[].class);
```

### Approach 2

Modify your JSON to be like:

```json
{
  "rawDatas": [
    {
      "tag": "Volume_D1_10m",
      "value": 0,
      "quality": 1,
      "site": 1,
      "supplier": 2,
      "zone": 0,
      "timestamp": 1470297561000
    },
    {
      "tag": "Tmoy_T4_10m",
      "value": 19.2,
      "quality": 1,
      "site": 1,
      "supplier": 2,
      "zone": 0,
      "timestamp": 1470297561000
    }
  ]
}
```

And then serialize it into a `RawDataBody`:

```java
String json = "{\"rawDatas\":[{\"tag\":\"Volume_D1_10m\",\"value\":0.0,\"quality\":1,\"site\":1,\"supplier\":2,\"zone\":0,\"timestamp\":1470297561000},{\"tag\":\"Tmoy_T4_10m\",\"value\":19.2,\"quality\":1,\"site\":1,\"supplier\":2,\"zone\":0,\"timestamp\":1470297561000}]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
RawDataBody rawDataBody = mapper.readValue(json, RawDataBody.class);
```

Comment: I am using API Retrofit, I call a webService and I'm getting a response. The response is a Json file. To be clearer, my purpose is to get the json file from the Response and create objects. I can't create a String because the Json file could change.

Comment: @AymenRagoubi Doesn't my approach work for you? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I can't do it like you said because I have a HTTP response, I don't know the content of the json file but i know the structure which i used it to create my model, so I can't create a string containing the json file.

Comment: @AymenRagoubi The code was an example to make it easier to test... I don't have the same environment you have. Use the same code you provided in your question: `mapper.readValue(response.getBody().in(), RawData[].class)`.

Comment: Cool, when i changed mapper.readValue RawDataBody by RawData[] it works. Thank you for your help.